# SWI Prolog Java interface Unsatisfied Link Error

Tags: java, swi-prolog

I am attempting to run SWI Prolog from Java and set my environment variables as instructed, double checked to make sure that I am using the 64-bit version with my 64-bit machine and installed the jar file in the correct place. However, I am still getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: jpl.fli.Prolog.thread_self()I
    at jpl.fli.Prolog.thread_self(Native Method)
    at jpl.Query.open(Query.java:286)
    at jpl.Util.textToTerm(Util.java:162)
    at jpl.Query.<init>(Query.java:198)
    at prologtest.PrologTest.main(PrologTest.java:20)
Java Result: 1
```

Can anyone help me figure out what I am missing here?

Comment: You seem to be receiving the same exception as the one in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12283471/1153801) question. Perhaps it might be of use.

Comment: That page was precisely the one I used to help me set the environment variables in the first place. Is there any other possible explanation for the unsastisfied link error?